So called "concrete completion" and how to understand that
I was told by many people that English is just crazy ;). Let me explain what I mean by that. I need to examples to do that.

When I did my homework I went outside

When I cooked she arrived


I mean single events in the past not something that happened many times. Now, people told me that 1 is fine and it shows that first I was done with my homework and later after doing that thing I went outside. The told me that it is like that because "did my homework" shows so called "clear and concrete completion". On the other hand they told me that "cooked" doesn't really show that "concrete completion" and they would only interpret my 2 example as a routine that cooking and arriving happend many times at the sime time. They told that to change that I would need to use past perfect and say "When I had cooked". Do you agree with that? If so how am I supposed to know what verbs show "concrete completion" because I don't really feel it?

Those people misinformed you. To get the meaning you intend, you need to say "When I had done my homework I went outside." Your sentence could mean that you always did your homework out of doors.

Anyway, no-one would say "When I had cooked...". It would be far more natural to say "When I had finished cooking...", "When the meal was ready..." etc. etc.

But  for instance "when I did my homework  I went to play with friends" would clearly show without perfect that I went there after my homework?

Whether or not the meaning is obvious, a native speaker would say "When I had done/finished my homework..."

It doesn't matter even if the meaning is really obvious? For instance " Whenever I fixed his car he paid me" even though  common sense implies paying happens after the repair is done  the sentence itself without perfect wouldn't imply that, correct?

You're better off using "after" in such contexts to indicate one event happens after another. Either "After I did my homework I went outside", or "After I had done my homework I went outside" would be fine (though context would have an effect). "When" has several meanings.

This question is similar to: Simple vs continuous clauses. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See also how to understand the meaning of the sentence and Understanding the meaning of simple tenses with conjunctions and Context in more important than tenses to show duration - all of which look to me like essentially the same question (from the same user?! :)

I told you that your example (1) implies 'on every occasion', not 'when I had finished'. Obviously your example using 'whenever' also means 'on every occasion'.

"English is just crazy"—it's true! Many other languages have their eccentricities, but English can be especially weird because it's been so influenced by so many sources.
I'm not sure these examples show its "craziness" the best, though. I think, rather, they show the power of context to shape meaning, and that's something that's true in most languages. Many language learners look for structures, formulas, patterns, and algorithms, and it's dismaying to start to see one and then find an exception that breaks it. I would give up on looking for "verbs show 'concrete completion,'" as if to memorize a list of them; these kind of differences aren't so much about the words used as about the situations we're in.
Consider the short sentence "That's it!" It can have many different meanings depending on context:

(I'm frustrated during a task) "That's it!" (Means I quit.)
"I can't find our car in the parking lot." [pointing] "That's it!" (Means "I am indicating the correct one.")
"I was nervous at first, but I realized I could do it." "That's it!" (Means an expression of encouragement, like "that's the spirit!" or "you go!")
"Is Chucky the movie with the creepy clown?" "That's It." (Means you're thinking of the wrong creepy movie.)

I would argue that with your two examples, the reason that "When I did my homework I went outside" conveys a completion and a sequence, while "When I cooked she arrived" conveys... well, some non-idiomatic confusion, but a suggestion of overlapping events... has nothing to do with types of verbs and everything to do with these ideas, no matter which words we use for them. I could say "I study! I play!" and there would be a sense that "I completed my studying and then began playing," simply because this concept, "work before play," is strongly reinforced in society. Similarly "I cook, she come" would have a sense of overlapping events simply because cooking is usually an activity with a vague duration. OR maybe it would imply causality: "Every time I start cooking, my dog comes into the kitchen." OR conditionality: "Haven't you noticed, man? Your girlfriend doesn't like your cooking! She never comes over to our house on the nights that you cook. But when I cook, she comes." All these depend on context to create different ideas, ideas that could be expressed in any language, and the sequence of events and their completion has more to do with these scenarios than with the choice of words like "cook" and "arrive."
Let me boil it down further:

Never expect words out of context to carry as much meaning as the context carries.
Never be surprised when the same patterns, used in different contexts, can have different meanings.

This is disappointing news for any learner—"You mean I have to memorize a new set of rules for every context?"—and is advantage that more natural, intuitive ("haphazard"?) approaches to learner, like "immersion" methods, can have over very analytical and systematic approaches. When you find yourself frustrated by the inability to form a pattern, just shrug it off and focus on the situation instead, and assure yourself that you'll get "a feeling" for varying situations given enough time.

I always return respect.

I would not call this "clear and concrete completion". I've never heard that term before. They might have meant to point out the difference between instantaneous actions and actions with a duration. If so, the person who advised you was wrong about the first example sentence.
"Doing homework" and "cooking" are both actions with a duration. It takes time to do them. When you use those verbs, you mean that some amount of time was spent doing them, even if you don't say what the duration was. Using the simple past tense in this sentence—"When I did my homework"—has the potential to sound awkward because it's unclear if you went outside during the duration or after it ended, and also unclear if you meant one time or many times. (It is possible that they could figure out what you meant based on the context, but it can still sound awkward because it doesn't match the sentence structure we're used to hearing.)
If you are talking about something that happened one time and was followed by another action, you should change the action to an instantaneous action to use the simple past tense.
"When I finished my homework, I went outside."
The past perfect tense can also be used; the difference between these can be difficult to understand, but here either one would be acceptable.
"When I had finished my homework, I went outside."
Finishing your homework is something that happens at one instant in time. Since cooking is also an action with a duration, if you mean that you cooked one time and she arrived after that, you should say:
"When I finished cooking, she arrived."
For an action that is already instantaneous, there is no need to do this.
"When I pressed the button, the room lit up."

In fact, "when I had pressed the button, the room lit up" gives the impression that there was some length of time between when the button was pressed and when the room lit up.

It seems you're basing your conclusions on a very limited set of data -- your current knowledge of English.
There are a number of perfectly idiomatic ways of expressing the ideas you want to express.
when is not precise enough for your purposes. Try after:

After I did my homework I went outside.

And you can use the past perfect with a past event that occurred after another past event:

I had finished cooking before she arrived.

Or you could use simple past there:

I finished cooking before she arrived.

And you can do so because the verb finished expresses lexically some of what that past perfect expresses aspectually.
If you want to say that when she arrived, you had already finished cooking:

She arrived after I had finished cooking.

If you want to say her arrival coincided with you putting the final touches on the meal and it was ready to be served:

Just as I finished cooking she arrived.


This doesn't really answer the question, which was: why is sentence 1. acceptable, but sentence 2. is unacceptable? (I actually might disagree with the premise, but this answer don't even address the question.)

"If you want to say that when she arrived, you had already finished cooking: 'She arrived after I had finished cooking.'" Rather than showing how "when" and "after" differ, you seem to have demonstrated how they're the same.

@PeterShor We disagree on what this rather rambling question has asked. You can answer questions as you see fit and I will do the same.

@HitenStyle I think not.In order to express the sequence of events with when  one needs to use the word already.   She arrived when I finished cooking is coincident, not after, unless the past perfect is used to establish a sense that the cooking had finished prior to her arrival.

@TimR: I think HitenStyle has done a great job of answering it; no need for me to answer as well.
